# sql request : return the list of the first 5 best orders by summing them according to the client's name

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am in the process of manipulating an SQL database. In fact, I need an SQL query that can return the list of the first 5 orders by summing them according to the name of the client.

To better explain: I have a table that contains a customer list and the price of each order according to the customer. At first, I want to sum up all the orders according to the customer and then extract the 5 best customers

The table :

```
price   client
  0,00  client1
200,00  client2
205,00  client5
312,00  client3
335,00  client2
502,00  client1
584,00  client5
602,00  client3
735,00  client1
335,00  client1
502,00  client4
584,00  client7
602,00  client8
735,00  client8
584,00  client9
602,00  client3
735,00  client1
335,00  client6
502,00  client4
```

Any idea, please?

Comment: Edit your question and (1) translate the title; (2) provide the results you want.

Comment: `row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY client ORDER BY price DESC) as rnk`... in a subquery, and `... WHERE rnk <= 5 ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Dense_Rank` in selecting Top N rows like this:

```
SELECT Client, Price 
FROM (
      SELECT client, 
             price, 
             DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Price DESC) AS rank 
     FROM (
           SELECT client,
                  SUM(price) AS Price
           FROM Table1
           GROUP BY client
          ) AS t1
    ) AS t2
WHERE rank <= 5
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
client   price
----------------
client1  2307.00
client3  1516.00
client8  1337.00
client4  1004.00
client5  789.00
```

Link To the demo:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ae7e8d09403d999ed645ebde33eeedde

**Why to use `Dense_Rank()`?**

Take a case if 6 clients having the same total price. So in that case, `LIMIT` or `Fetch First` will not work since you will not get all 6 clients while all 6 are best customers.

Comment: @KhouloudLenGliz If you find it useful Please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically `order by` and `fetch first`:

```
select client, sum(price)
from t
group by client
order by sum(price) desc
fetch first 5 rows only;
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of group by and limit would do:

```
SELECT client, sum(price)
FROM p
GROUP BY client
ORDER BY sum(price) DESC
LIMIT 5;
```